# In line 14 of my code publish.py, what would be the service_account_path and how can i download this path?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

In the code below, i am getting one error attached. Also there is a service_account_path i have to enter, where do i find this path and how can i download this file?

```
 # Replace with your service account path
path_service_account = 'service1'

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = path_service_account    

# Replace  with your input file path
input_file = 'C:\tumbling window\store_sales.csv'

# create publisher
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: What is the error? Also, the code doesn't look to be complete as it has fewer than 14 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Client libraries make use of [service account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#before-you-begin) to authenticate into GCP services and APIs, such as Pub/Sub.

To do this, an environment variable named `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` needs to be set and its value is a string with the path of the JSON key value of that service account.

First, you need to make sure that you've [created a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) with [enough permissions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#roles) to do the required Pub/Sub operations:

- In the Cloud Console, go to the [Service accounts page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts).
- Select your project.
- Click Create service account.
- Enter a service account name to display in the Cloud Console.
- Choose one or more IAM roles to grant to the service account on the project. This is an important step, if you're only planning to use this account to consume the Pub/Sub service, then you could grant it the [Pub/Sub admin role](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#roles). If your code also makes use of another service (Such as BigQuery, for example) you need to grant the required roles as well. An easy option would be to grant it the Project Editor role, which grants access to all GCP services, but is always a recommended security practice to grant only the required minimal necessary permissions.
- Once you've granted the required role(s), click Done to finish creating the service account.

Once you've created the service account, then you need to [generate a JSON key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys):

- In the Cloud Console, go to the [Service accounts page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts).
- Select your project.
- Find the row of the service account that you want to create a key for. In that row, click the More (3-dot) button, and then click Create key.
- Select a JSON Key type and click Create.
- Clicking Create downloads a service account key file.

That is the file which path needs to be referenced in `path_service_account`. Let's say that your JSON key file was downloaded in `C:\Downloads\YOUR_JSON_KEY_FILENAME.json`, then your code would be something like:

```
path_service_account = 'C:\Downloads\YOUR_JSON_KEY_FILENAME.json'
```

This should solve the authentication errors that you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was helpfull

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you, please consider accepting the answer so other community members can see that it can help them as well.